# String parsing, turn LED on/off based on received serial data

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

I am receiving in the serial port from python a string in this format **(0,77,88,55)**.
I have the first number randomized to either be 0 or 1, the rest are fixed.

```
import random
import serial
import time

last_time = 0
test_list = [0,1]

serialSTM32 = serial.Serial('COM22',9600,writeTimeout=0)

while True:
    if (time.time() - last_time) > 2:
        random_num = random.choice(test_list)
        #string = str(random_num)
        string = "(" + str(random_num) + "," + "77" + "," + "88" + "," + "55" + ")"
        serialSTM32.write(string.encode('utf-8'))
        print(string)
        last_time = time.time()
        serialSTM32.flushInput()
```

The STM32 MCU is receiving through the virtual serial COM port the data through a variable in the "usbd_cdc_if.c" file:

```
uint8_t bufferVariable = 0;

static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  bufferVariable = Buf[0];
  return (USBD_OK);
}
```

The bufferVariable is passed to the "main.c" file using:

```
extern uint8_t bufferVariable;
```

The "main.c" is then parsing the data, splitting the data and placing the first number which is '0' or '1' in a variable named "first", the second number which is '77' in a variable named "second" etc.
I am taking the "first" variable to see if it is '1' to turn on the LED, but if it is '0' to turn off the LED.
Program waits for start market "(" and keeps reading until it reaches end marker ")", then parses the data in between the two. **Works well on Arduino from parsing tutorial a while back, i converted everything to work on STM32 MCU....

**For this STM32 controller, previously, I tested without the parsing, only receiving '1' or '0' through serial to turn on/off the LED **which works**.....but now I am using the format (0,77,88,55) which includes parsing the data then getting the value extracted from that format. **This part is not working....LED does not turn on or off.

"main.c" file code:

```
#define buffer_size 40

char input_buffer[buffer_size];
const char start_marker = '(';
const char end_marker = ')';
uint8_t bytes_received = 0;
uint8_t read_in_progress = 0;

char* grab_value(char *data, char separator, int index) {
    int found = 0;
    int string_index[] = { 0, -1 };
    int maximum_index = strlen(data) - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= maximum_index && found <= index; i++) {
        if (data[i] == separator || i == maximum_index) {
            found++;
            string_index[0] = string_index[1] + 1;
            string_index[1] = (i == maximum_index) ? i + 1 : i;
        }
    }

    if (found > index) {
        data[string_index[1]] = '\0';
        return &data[string_index[0]];
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int first, second, third, fourth;

extern uint8_t bufferVariable;

int main(void) {

    while (1) {

        if (bufferVariable == end_marker) {
            read_in_progress = 0;
            input_buffer[bytes_received] = '\0';
        }

        if (read_in_progress) {
            input_buffer[bytes_received++] = bufferVariable;
            if (bytes_received == buffer_size) {
                bytes_received = buffer_size - 1;
            }
        }

        if (bufferVariable == start_marker) {
            bytes_received = 0;
            read_in_progress = 1;
        }
        char *str_first = grab_value(input_buffer, ',', 0);
        char *str_second = grab_value(input_buffer, ',', 1);
        char *str_third = grab_value(input_buffer, ',', 2);
        char *str_fourth = grab_value(input_buffer, ',', 3);

        if (str_first) {
            first = atoi(str_first);
        }
        if (str_second) {
            second = atoi(str_second);
        }
        if (str_third) {
            third = atoi(str_third);
        }
        if (str_fourth) {
            fourth = atoi(str_fourth);
        }
        printf("first: %d\n", first);

        if (first == '0') {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        } else if (first == '1') {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your code assumes that `CDC_Receive_FS` always receives a single byte, but function prototype tells, that it can receive a buffer of arbitrary length. As I told you in your previous question - now you have to work with a buffer, not just single bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first == '0'
```

It is completely wrong. `'0'` is not **zero** integer value only `48` in ASCII representing the character `'0'`.

Do not reinvent the wheel.

After the whole sting reception simply:

```
if(sscanf(inputBuffer, "(%d,%d,%d,%d)", &first, &second, &third, &fourth) == 4)
{
    if(!first) HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    else HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}
```

STM32 uCs have much more resources than AVR uCs used in Arduino and you do not need any "tricks"
Only make sure that `inputBuffer` is null character terminated

Comment: thanks, your sscanf function works and thanks to @Flexz because of the `"work with a buffer, not just single bytes"` advice.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, this is my personal preference:

For embedded, you should never use blocking I/O, always buffered, interrupt-driven I/O. I cannot say a single thing in favor of blocking I/O except it's simpler.

You say the problem is, that the LED doesn't toggle.

Let's look at the facts.

This check controls whether or not to toggle the LED:

```c
if (first == '0') {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
} else if (first == '1') {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}
```

I notice that you're comparing an integer with the `char`-values for 0 and 1 and not the integer values. You're essentially checking if `first == 48/49` instead of 0/1 (see integer values https://www.asciitable.com/)

At the same time, you're converting the received string to an integer by doing

`first = atoi(str_first);`

Compare `first` against `0` or `1` instead of `'0'` and `'1'` (which are 48 and 49 respectively).

Comment: `For embedded, you should never use blocking I/O, always buffered, interrupt-driven I/O.` is basically wrong. Simply code like above can use blocking stuff (all arduino code does it). Always interrupt is completely wrong as you also have DMA and other mechanisms to archive that.

Comment: I'll add a disclaimer about it being my personal opinion. I still would not use blocking I/O for this.

Comment: BTW it is not blocking. Do you know how USB on STM32 works?

Comment: @0___________ I am only familiar with USB HID on STM32, not virtual COM-port over USB.

Comment: @0___________ I would not say the comment on blocking I/O is wrong, but rather it is one of context. For trivial programs that do nothing but read a sensor or blink an LED, blocking I/O is fine -- there are no consequences for a stall waiting on a condition. However, for more substantial programs, blocking I/O is a death sentence. Consider a guidance, nav and control system that blocks preventing attitude correction. (splat, augered-in, or nothing left but a smoking hole -- would result....)